# Unable to display image on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Image is not being rendered on `index.html`. The `index.html, app.js` and image file are all located in a VM. I have `login.js` and upon successful login the page routes to `index.html`, every element of index file is loading except for `<img>`.

**index.html**

```
<img id="image1" src="/images/apple.png"/>
```

**app.js**

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));
```

**Error (browser console)**

```
GET http://vm_name.com:1050/root/project/public/images/apple.png 404 (Not Found)
```

**Directory structure**

```
|-project
    |
    |-login.js
    |-index.html
    |-a.html
    |-a.js
    |-b.html
    |-b.js
    |-public(folder)
        |
        |-images(folder)
            |
            |-apple.png
```

If I tree my project it has 544 directories, 2960 files on the Linux server/vm.

Let me give you the file structure idea in short.

```
/root/project/ ls -> index.html, 
                     app,js, 
                     public 
cd public/images 
ls -lrt 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19834 Aug 25 04:24 apple.png
```

Comment: Can you show the script tag that is loaded correctly?

Comment: not sure, but can you try removing __dirname and directly use, app.use(express.static('public'));

Comment: show you directory structure

Comment: @Raghuveer getting the below error `GET http://vm_name.com:1050/images/apple.png 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: ```app.use(express.static(__dirname +'public'));``` remove ```/```

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh no luck. Th file directory is 
`/root/project/public/images
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19834 Aug 25 04:24 apple.png`

Comment: and where is your ```app.js``` file resides. ```__dirname```  gives the location of the file in which it is called.

Comment: does `apple.png` even exist under `/root/project/public/images/apple.png`?

Comment: Yes, it is. Also given `chmod 777 apple.png`

Comment: `404` is returned from your backend. so either your request URL is wrong or the requested resource does not exist at all.

Comment: @messerbill - the file exists in the above-mentioned directory. All the HTML files are accessible (wrt to login.js port) except for this png image which I intend to display on the HTML container.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try it with the path:
`http://vm_name.com:1050/images/apple.png`

Comment: The images are kept inside this directory - 
`/root/project/public/images
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19834 Aug 25 04:24 apple.png`

Answer (score 0):

If you have directory structure like this

```
|-app.js
|
|-public(folder)
   |
   |-image(folder)
      |
      |-imagename.jpg

//add in app.js
const path = require('path'); //prior save path module in project folder using npm i path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: If your project directory is not like this then you need to show how you setup your project

Comment: If I tree my project it has `544 directories, 2960 files` on the Linux sever/vm. Let me give you the file structure idea in short.

`/root/project/`
`ls -> index.html, app,js, public`
`cd public/images`
`ls -lrt -> -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19834 Aug 25 04:24 apple.png`

Comment: i think this answer should work. your directory structure looks like as I guessed

Comment: `index.html:109 GET http://vm_name:1050/images/apple.png 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: And if I keep the file inside project dir same as index.html and app.js and src as `apple.png` then it is giving error  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: @mplungjan I have already used this (it was not working). 

`GET http://vm_name.com:100//images/apple.png 404 (Not Found)`
considering the img path remains same `<img id="image1" src="/images/apple.png"/>`

Comment: I’m not the poster here

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I am fully aware of that :) could you please help me out with this? Not able to figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: I have no clue. Never used It

Comment: My HTML pretty much renders everything except for the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think `<img id="image1" src="/images/apple.png"/>` has to replaced with `<img id="image1" src="./images/apple.png">`.

**Edit**:
Make sure your folder looks somewhat like this: [image: FOLDER!!!!!!1111]
and the `images` folder with the image right inside of it. Also make sure the image name is the same.

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`